# How to fix error in loading data from Azure blob?

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to read data from azure blob.

```
df = spark.read.load('abfs[s]://folder/a_p_c_w.csv')
sf.show(5)
```

But getting below error. Can someone help me here.

```
IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name 
at index 4: abfs[s]://folder/a_p_c_w.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 204, in load
return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))

File "/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
return_value = get_return_value(

File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
raise converted from None

pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal 
character in scheme name at index 4: 
abfs[s]://folder/a_p_c_w.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

abfs[s] isnt a valid url. hence the error message "Illegal
character in scheme name at index 4"

the scheme you want is abfs: